# How to make the roles radio button mandatory in the register form. drupal 8

Tags: forms, drupal, roles

I have Drupal 8 site and I’m using the Select registration roles module to allow the user to choose its role during the registration process. and It works fine. but I want to make it mandatory to choose from the radio buttons.

any idea how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For making it required, we can alter the form using `hook_form_alter()` inside `.module file`.

Add the following code.

```
if ($form_id == "user_register_form") {
    $form['select_roles']['#required'] = TRUE;
}
```